# Standard Customer DIXF entity updating address with wrong city because we have same zipcodes for Different cities . Ax 2012R2

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, dynamics-ax-xpo

We have same zipcode for different cities
zipcode1 city1
zipcode1 city2
zipcode1 city3

When i am loading address with city as City2, DIXF is loading address with City as City1. 
Its picking first record in that list.

How can i fix this??? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the issue. In AX while using dixf its checking zipcode based on zipcode, country in csv but its not considering city. So its inserting first zipcode that its finding and city attached to that is getting Updated. I made a fix for that by writing job and updating LogisticsPostalAddress record(city,zipcode fields) for that Customer based on csv.

Job I wrote 
gets city,zipcode, state, country from csv and finds zipcode (logisticsaddresszipcodetable) by using state,zipcode,country,city.
Same for city i found using state, zipcode, city, country. 
Then i updated it in LogisticsPostalAddress Table for that customer.

Comment: Thanks @AlexKwitny, good to know. I think the hotfix is [KB 4034045 DIXF entity LogisticsAddtressZIPCode can only accept an input file with unique values in the ZipCode field](https://fix.lcs.dynamics.com/Issue/Details/1196432?kb=4034045)

Comment: Nope, that only adds the CountryRegionId to the unique key. I think [KB 4013430 Importing a vendor address using DIXF processing creates duplicate ZIP/postal codes](https://fix.lcs.dynamics.com/Issue/Details/1196432?kb=4013430) is the right one.